# RxJava's replay(time, unit) is replaying "expired" emissions. Is that the expected behavior?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm doing the following:

```
Observable source = Observable.amb(Arrays.asList(source1, source2))
    .replay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .autoConnect();
```

Then when testing:

```
    source.subscribe(obj -> {
        if (obj.equals(obj1)) {
            print("same object 1");
        }
    });

    source.subscribe(obj -> {
        if (obj.equals(obj1)) {
            print("same object 1");
        }
    });

    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        source.subscribe(obj -> {
            if (!obj.equals(obj1)) {
                 print("Emitted another object");
            }
        });
    }, 120000);
```

However, "Emitted another object" never gets printed. When debugging, the 3rd subscription never calls the source1 or source2 and emits the same `obj1` again. Is that the normal behavior here? If so, is there a way to force calling the original sources with `replay`, once the expected timeout is expired?

Comment: Amb will pick one of the sources (not shown) and replay will cache its values with a 1 minute timeout.  Each 3 subscribers should receive the same values because you told the stream to cache the results of amb. You have to manually disconnect and reconnect the ConnectableObservable the replay() returns.

Comment: But I told it to cache for 1 minute only, no? The late subscriber should not be receiving it if I'm understanding the docs correctly.

Comment: This seems to be the same problem reported here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3917 where a late subscriber receives an old emission.

Answer (score 0):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5139) fixed on version [2.0.7](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5142).

Once the version is published, this should work:

```
io.reactivex.schedulers.TestScheduler scheduler = new io.reactivex.schedulers.TestScheduler();

io.reactivex.Observable<Integer> source = io.reactivex.Observable.just(3)
                .replay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler)
                .autoConnect();

source.test().assertResult(3);

source.test().assertResult(3);

scheduler.advanceTimeBy(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

source.test().assertResult();
```